# ActiveAdmin precompile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

When I try to precompile my assets using 
`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
I get this error.
Is there anything I can do to fix it myself? It comes from the gem's scss.
I only get this error when I import the active_admin.scss in my application.scss because I need to customise the admin panel

```
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Undefined operation: "3rem 1.5rem times 2".
        on line 253:48 of ../../.rbenv/versions/2.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-2.6.1/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_forms.scss
        from line 8:9 of ../../.rbenv/versions/2.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-2.6.1/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.scss
        from line 12:9 of app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss
        from line 57:9 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
>> bar-inner-content-width: $sidebar-width - ($section-padding * 2);

   ------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your SassC version?(You can check by using "sassc --version"). Try to change the version of SassC and retry. In my case I used previous version of SassC.

Comment: I'm using: 
sassc 3.4.5
libsass 3.4.8
sass2scss 1.1.1
sass 3.4